# How to send multiple array objects to ejs template

Tags: node.js, express

```
var results = [];
var categories = [];

async.parallel({
  results: function(callback) {
    const query2 = client.query('SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY id desc');
    query2.on('row', (row) => {
      results.push(row);
    });

    query2.on('end', () => {
      callback(null, results);
    })
  },
  categories: function(callback) {
    const query3 = client.query('SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id desc');
    // Stream results back one row at a time
    query3.on('row', (row) => {
      categories.push(row);
    });

    query3.on('end', () => {
      callback(null, categories);
    });
  }
}, function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    return res.send(err);
  }
  return res.render('index2.ejs',{"results" : results, "categories" :categories});
});
```

This is what I have done....But it still doesn't work

Comment: In addition to your other problems, you want to move the `results`, and `categories` declaration within their respective callbcak wrappers. This way on each subsequent call, new results would get added to the array - it would not get emptied out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's how you use your async.parallel results:

```
async.parallel({
  numbers: function(cb) { cb(null, [1, 2, 3]); },
  letters: function(cb) { cb(null, ['a', 'b']); }
},
function (err, results) {
  console.log(results); // "{ numbers: [ 1, 2, 3 ], letters: [ 'a', 'b' ] }"
});
```

So in your case:

```
async.parallel({
  results: firstQueryCB, 
  categories: secondQueryCB
}, 
function everything(err, results) {
  if (err) { throw err; // actually do something. }
  // your `results` is now `{results: [], categories: []}`
  res.render('index2.ejs', {
    results: results.results,
    categories: results.categories,
  });
})
```

Comment: Have any errors? Or simply ejs empty? What does your template look like?  Might be something with your database response not being what you expect it to be.

Comment: I am getting the response as json.....but cant pass the 2 arrays to the ejs template

Comment: I cant pass the results in this line:
 return res.render('index2.ejs',{results: results.results, categories: results.categories});

Comment: I'm aware you can't, you said so in the question. I'm asking why not? Do you see any errors?
What do you see if you replace `res.render(...)` line with `console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2))`?

Comment: I just don't get the output on browser....I haven't written appropriate error functions in my application

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` library to solve the issue.

```
var async = require('async');

var results2 = [];
var categories2 = [];

async.parallel({
  results: function(callback) {
    const query2 = client.query('SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY id desc');
    query2.on('row', (row) => {
      results2.push(row);
    });

    query2.on('end', () => {
      callback(null, results2);
    })
  },
  categories: function(callback) {
    const query3 = client.query('SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id desc');
    // Stream results back one row at a time
    query3.on('row', (row) => {
      categories2.push(row);
    });

    query2.on('end', () => {
      callback(null, categories2);
    });
  }
}, function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    return res.send(err);
  }
  return res.render('index2.ejs',results);
});
```